# Getting images in WatchKit app from iOS app

Tags: ios, image, watchkit, apple-watch

I'd like to show in a WatchKit app the user's avatar image from its paired iOS app. Such image is downloaded by the iOS app querying a REST web service when the user logs in the app. How could I get it from the WatchKit app?

The downloaded avatar is persisted as a .jpeg file in the Documents folder of the iOS app.

Comment: Is it persisted somewhere in the iOS app?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Transferring the image from the host to the extension? How extension can access URL? Please provide more data about your issue. it sounds too simple, so...

Comment: @stk Yes, the image file is persisted in the app's Documents folder

Comment: @Idan as I said, I create the image file in Documents folder. How could I make the `WatchKit` app to access and show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your issue is to write the avatar image out to the [App Group](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW6) directory instead of the Documents directory in the iOS app. Then you can load the avatar image from the App Group file system directly from the Watch Extension. In order to do this, you'll need to make the following changes.

#### Step by Step

- Add an App Group to your iOS app and Watch Extension
- Write the avatar image to the App Group instead of the Documents directory
- Read the avatar image out of the App Group in the Watch Extension
- Push the avatar image into the `WKInterfaceDevice` shared image cache
- Apply the image to either a `WKInterfaceImage` or `WKInterfaceGroup` to be displayed

Hopefully that helps make things a bit more clear.

Comment: I used this process but the image I want to load is created in runtime. So I am not able to display the image.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you download the image from a REST service or generate the image dynamically at runtime, the approach will still work just fine. I have used the above approach to composite images on the iPhone app and display them on the Watch, it works great!